# Frequency vector and fft

Tags: fft, matlab, frequency, frequency-spectrum

I have got a question concerning the definition of the frequency vector for an fft operation.

Generally, I work with a frequency vector, `f`, with power of 2 elements (2048, 4096, 8192, ...).

Given a certain simulation analysis time, `time` (e.g. 600s), I should define `f` as follows:

```
% Frequency defition
t = 0:dt:(time-dt);
df = 1/(time);
fn = Nfft/time;
```

$$ f = -f_{n}/2:df:f_{n}/2-1; $$

where $ f_{n} $ represent the Nyquist cut-off frequency.

Actually, for:

- computational reasons
- symmetry of the power spectra along `f` axis
- not throwing away `real` or `imag` part of the `fft`

I aim to define only half of the frequency range, as for example

$$ f = 0:df:f_{n}/2-1; $$

After calling the `fft` of my input signal, I would get the desired time series as

```
ouput = [real(fft) imag(fft)];
```

But, this way, I count the `0` frequency term twice and the `-fn/2` is completely discarded.

How would it be possible to emcompasses the whole standard frequency range starting from only half of it?

Comment: Maybe `fftshift` will help you?

Comment: how should `fftshift` be helpful? `fftshift` is only meant to center the `fft` results about the `0` component.

Comment: I mean that `fft` return vector for frequencies from 0 to $f_n-1$, `fftshift` moves zero to center and frequencies vector would be exactly $[ -f_n/2 : df : f_n/2 -1 ]$. I think, I don't understand your question.

Comment: sorry my bad: I'm already doing this; but ain't I counting `0` component twice this way?

Comment: No, you will meet component with zero frequency only once: in the middle of vector returning by `fftshift`. IF you don't want to have a deal with another half of fft, you can just trim it to only first half.

Comment: I have done an easy test: `f = (0:df/2:fn/2-1)` and `fff = fftshift([-fliplr(f) f])`. As I expect `0` is counted twice, first and last vector's elements.

Comment: @fpe your simple test is flawed: you are inserting `0` twice yourself when you do `[-fliplr(f) f]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to define your frequency vector after a DFT is as follows. Let $N$ be your DFT length, and $f_s$ be your sampling rate in Hz. Furthermore, define an $N$-length frequency vector $\bf{f}$, where each element $f_i = i$, for $i = 0, 1, 2, ... N-1$.

Now your frequency vector in hertz is simply going to be $\bf{f}$$\frac{f_s}{N}$

Now, assuming you are DFT'ing a real sequence, simply pick all elements with frequency values less than $\frac{f_s}{2}$, and you are in business!

You can also see my answer [here for actual code](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8508/finding-the-dominant-tone-in-a-signal/8510#8510).

Comment: but I dft complex numbers and not real sequences: does your approach apply anyway?

Comment: @fpe If you are DFT'ing complex sequences, then you need all the frequency vector, meaning all the negative frequencies, and all the positive frequencies. There is no redundancy. If however you are DFT'ing a real sequence, then you can just take half of the frequency vector, since there is redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple 
Frequency step for DFT is

**freqStep = sampling_frequency / sample_count**

linear independent frequency bin count for fft (up to Nyquist cut-off frequency) is 
for even sample count:

**N = samples / 2 + 1**

for even sample count:

**N = (samples - 1) / 2 + 1**

The whole number of bins in FFT equal to the sampe count

First frequency bin is a zero frequency one. Second one is the bin for freqStep frequency and so on. The N-th bin is the bin for the Nyquist cut-off frequency. Bins after N are bins those values are complex conjugated symmetrically by N, i.e

**fft(N - i) == conj(fft(N + i))**

for the 5 - point signal the bins are:

**[0]

[f1]

[f2]

[-f2]

[-f1]**


frequency for f1 is 
**f1: 1 * freqStep**,
 frequency for f2 is 
**f2: 2 * freqStep**

for the 4 - point signal the bins are:

**[0]

[f1]

[f2]

[-f1]**


frequency for f1 is 
**f1: 1 * freqStep**,
 frequency for f2 is 
**f2: 2 * freqStep**