# Computing narrowband spectrograms using MATLAB

Tags: stft, transform, fourier

I'm having an assignment of computing narrowband spectrograms using MATLAB.
And I totally have no idea about the code.
Can someone help me writing the code and explaining what's going on to me.
Lots of thanks!!

Followings are the requirement:

B.1. Load the recorded .wav file using the function “wavread”. Let y be the variable
storing the signal;

B.2. Perform short-time Fourier transform on y as follows:
(i) Divide the signal into many short-time frames. Each frame is 50 msec long. Frame
shift is 1 msec;

(ii) Apply 1024-point FFT on each frame;

(iii) Store the power spectrum of each frame in a column vector (note that only the first
512 FFT coefficients are needed).

(iv) Append the power spectrum vectors of all frames to form super matrix S. The size
of the matrix will be 512 × no. of frames;
(v) Plot the spectrogram using the following MATLAB commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one is going to give you a full working code - the point is that you should **learn** and **understand** how to do it. Following guidelines for you:

1. As given, use the [wavread](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/wavread.html) function to load the recording (please mind that in the newest 2014a version this function is deprecated, you should use [audioread](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html) instead). MATLAB has wonderful help with very good examples, so simply use it.
2. Having your signal loaded, together with its sampling frequency, you need to split it into chunks (*many short-time frames*). This can be done in two ways, either you are using a loop construct (for, while - whichever you prefer), or (my favourite) use the MATLAB [buffer](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/signal/ref/buffer.html) function (please consider using `'nodelay'` option in it, as first frame will have zeros in it up to overlap length). Although you require the Signal Processing Toolbox license (I'm sure your University has it). This function allows you to specify the length of frame, overlapping and other things. In result you will obtain the matrix which columns are your signal frames. Having the sampling frequency from `wavread`, it is very easy to calculate corresponding length of your frame in samples for given number of miliseconds
3. Now you can iterate over the columns of your matrix and calculate the FFT for each of them. You might want to use the [fft](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/fft.html) function to get it. In extra parameter you can specify the length of your signal (to apply zero padding eventually). So let's say that now you have FFT for first frame. Now take the magnitude of it ([abs](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/abs.html?searchHighlight=abs)), and choose first 512 samples. Store this result into fist column of your *super matrix* $S$. **Optional step:** before calculating the FFT, I suggest you to multiply your frame by the window function, i.e. [hamming](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/signal/ref/hamming.html?searchHighlight=hamming) window.
4. Now you have the matrix $S$, so plotting can be done by using various functions ([pcolor](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html), [imagesc](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html?searchHighlight=imagesc), and so on - pick whichever you prefer).

I suggest you to compare the final result with MATLAB built-in [spectrogram](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html) function.

Good luck!

Comment: I don't quite understand the meaning of overlapping in the function buffer.. Is it referring to the frame shift??

Comment: @Hiya: Yes, you've got it correct! 50% overlap means that you shift your frame of length $L$ by $0.5 * L$. So in your case overlapp is $1-\dfrac{1}{50}=98\%$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!!!!:) I'm trying my best to work on it

Comment: @Hiya: That's OK - we are here to help. Task is very simple, so you should finish it very soon.

Comment: I save y as my sample by [y,Fs]=wavread('song.wav'); then split it by y=buffer(y,80,16); then I've got a matrix of 80x749; how could I separate the matrix into columns that represent each of the frames?

Comment: @Hiya: Do a loop then over number of columns (`size(y, 2)`) and extract each of these by using the MATLAB colon operator: `y(i, :)`. As simple as that.

Comment: for size(y,2), what's the meaning of the '2'?? Is it meaning that I'm separating the matrix by row?

Comment: @Hiya: That's the dimension you are considering. If any doubts please refer to MATLAB help first - that's a real goldmine!

Comment: sorry to disturb again.. i'm wondering whether i will get the same result by fft the whole matrix and by fft the matrix column by column. since I saw that "If the input X is a matrix, Y = fft(X) returns the Fourier transform of each column of the matrix" from the matlab help

Comment: @Hiya: You are right, that's the default behaviour of `fft`. I intentionally omitted that part because if you want to apply the window to each frame, then you would have to use `repmat` function in order to replicate your window vector and use element-wise multiplication of the two matrices: `Y.*W`. I did not wanted to scare you with more advanced approach, but it seems like you can cope with that ;) In result you can take the `abs` of whole matrix, use the colon operator `Z = Y(1:512,:)` and you are done. One last thing - do not forget about scaling of the FFT by the sum of window samples!

Comment: I've some problems with the dimensions.. as the question required, each frame contains 80 samples, then how could I get 512 samples from each frame? Is it about zero padding?

Comment: @Hiya: Yes - this is about zero padding. You need to specify the second argument in `fft` function (__n__). Don't forget that you must specify __n__ as 1024, then you take first 512 samples (spectrum is mirrored). Also please mind that you might want to use the `'nodelay'` option in the buffer function. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Finally, I got a matrix S with dimension 512x749 but according to the question the dimension of S should be 512x(number of frames), by hand calculation, the number of frames should be 2991, and I can't figure out where is the problem...

Comment: @Hiya: You do realise, that there is no way for me to debug your code remotely without seeing it? Please edit your original question, pasting code you've got so far (and preferably a link to the recording) and then I am more than happy to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I've just realize my problem. Really thanks so much for your help. I am a new user of matlab and I've learnt a lot:)

Comment: @Hiya: Great! So results are consistent with `spectrogram` function? I hope I've convinced you to do things on your own for learning and satisfaction. Best of luck!

Comment: SUre. You are such a kind man:) Really appreciate your patience and afford!

Comment: I would like to go further more.. if I want to multiple the hamming window before applying fft, should I create a 1024-point by "w = hamming(1024)" ?

Comment: @Hiya: That depends how are you zero-padding your signal. I presume it is done by invoking `fft(Y, 1024)` on the matrix $Y$ returned by `buffer` function? Then you must create a Hamming window with number of samples equal to frame length (80 was it?), and replicate it to be same size as $Y$ (each column should be a one window) --> `repmat`. After that use the `.*` operator and it is done. Just remember about normalisation factor `sum(win)`. One last word - don't forget about creating time and frequency axes: `meshgrid` will be useful.

Comment: Please move this conversation into a chat room. Or ask more questions. The system is flagging this as having too many comments.

Comment: @PeterK. I've tried, but for the moment as you can see it cannot be done. I need to wait until Hiya will have 20 points of reputation. Or if you can override that, then please do so.

Comment: @jojek So Hiya can't go to: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1090/signal-processing ??  Hmm. Perhaps it does need 20 rep.

Comment: the assignment require me to use "image(t, f, S*10)" to show the axis.. I'm wondering how to find out the "t" and "f" in it..

Comment: my code first read the signal, then use a buffer function to split it into frames, then I apply 1024-point fft to the whole matrix, then take abs of it, and finally take the first 512 samples in each column and save it into S

Comment: @Hiya: First, create the time vector $t$ - starting from 0 seconds, with step of overlap shift. Then create the frequency vector $f$, more info [here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8556/frequency-vector-and-fft). At last, use the function I mentioned above to create the grids. Play with different kinds of plots to see best results. Detailed examples can be found in MATLAB help and on this forum.

Comment: I'v understood the frequency, but can't deal with the time, what does "with step of overlap shift" means? if my number of frame is 2946, and each frame is 50ms long. Is it correct for I to create the time vector by "time = [0:2946-1].*(0.05)"?

Comment: @Hiya: It's hard to explain here. I suggest you to draw the frames on paper, and how you shift each of them by 1 msec. This will give you a clue how to choose time. Nevertheless step must be equal to frame shift. Also check the final value of the time vector.

Comment: Finally, I've finished my project, credits to jojek:) really thanks so much for your patience, I'm such an matlab idiot.

Comment: By following these steps, what would would be the difference between a narrowband and wideband spectrogram? What would I have to do to generate a wideband spectrogram instead?